# Mailing attachments using the ruby mail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am using the Mail gem to send out emails with attachments from my application. Specifically, I have identical code living on my devbox and a server machine which is used to report a pdf file. However, pdfs sent as attachments from my devbox show up in Thunderbird and other clients fine, whereas attachments from the server show up only in SOME (not thunderbird) mail clients fine. I've opened the email source to compare the two and try to get some insight into the issue:

Devbox:

```
--_av-F3fhmdkLZDU59RCz4nm2gw--

--_av-ycGAp26idM_6kl-0lMcYmw
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNjc4L0ZpbHRlci9G
bGF0ZURlY29kZT4+c3RyZWFtCnic7Zhdb9owFIZ7S37FuZm0SZA53wkSF1Bg
...
MzBhN2RlZDE0ZmJkZDMwNzU1MzU2Y2ZhPjxlYTM0OTMzOTEwN2RmYzI1NTJh
NDE5NTJmNDhmN2MwMD5dL0luZm8gMzMgMCBSL1NpemUgMzQ+PgpzdGFydHhy
ZWYKNDE2NjQKJSVFT0YK

--_av-ycGAp26idM_6kl-0lMcYmw--
```

Server:

```
----==_mimepart_561d49a469c4d_33ee3fea57ad63b8624ae
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 charset=UTF-8;
 filename=report.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=report.pdf
Content-ID: <561d49a46bc9f_33ee3fea57ad63b862596@autopilot-demo-east-web-1.mail>

JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNjgwL0ZpbHRlci9G
bGF0ZURlY29kZT4+c3RyZWFtCnic7Zhdb9owFIZ7S37FuZm0SSVznJAPJC4o
oWs7qrVdql500xTAgNt8QGKg3a+fnQ5RbR3ttnYziQkR9jk+Pu95bEcKM+0V
nPjWcQ8WJMtpmjTBdI3RjQEnWcp9R/77tcfQbR19MW1u//Bxbe7RZH4Dpo51
..
N2I0MjdlNTE4ZTNmZGNmOGE5YzY1NTRjMzc+PGE1N2MzNmNkNTE0ZTQ1Mzlk
ZjY3OTU2ODZkY2M2ZDEzPl0vSW5mbyAzMyAwIFIvU2l6ZSAzND4+CnN0YXJ0
eHJlZgo0MTY2NgolJUVPRgo=

----==_mimepart_561d49a469c4d_33ee3fea57ad63b8624ae--
```

The simple line adding the attachment (Rails):

`email.add_file filename: "sample.pdf", content: File.read("/public/sample.pdf")`

Off the bat, the section identifiers are different (_av vs mimepart) and the way each attachment is encoded is also different after a few lines. My question is, what could be causing certain clients not to respect the "mimepart" sections as attachments? Beyond that, the next question would be why the same code would generate different output, but if I know the underlying issue I may be able to solve that myself. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using same versions of all your gems on both developement and server? If you are using Rails, you have a Gemfile.lock -- make sure it is identical on server and development machine. Otherwise, different versions of gems is one thing that could result in different behavior.

Comment: Yes they are identifical

Comment: Then I have no explanation for how they could be behaving differently either. Different input? Something has got to be different. If you are doing the exact same thing with the exact same code on two different machines and getting different results... it seems like there must be something different, not really the exact same code or exact same input.  But I'm not sure what it could be either.

Comment: So there was a difference in how postfix was sending the email out. Devbox was using mandrill as the relay host, the other was using native postfix on the server to send it directly. I'd still like to know why the mimepart boundary identifier from the server isn't being respected by Thunderbird though.